# How to receive/access headers of the POST request and 'User Properties' from Data Factory task in Azure Function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'm still new to Azure, so please bear with me if this is a newbie question.

I created a task in Azure Data Factory that will invoke a Http-triggered Python function (Consumption plan). The settings and user properties of that task is as shown below:

[image]

and here

[image]

The function itself is as shown below:

[image]

**Q1:** I'd like to know how to read/access the headers of the POST request in the Python function ('run.py' in the screenshot above). For now, I could only access the body of the HTTP request by using `os.environ['req']`.

**Q2:** I'd also like to know if it's possible to access 'User Properties' in the 'run.py' assuming that I run the task in the Data Factory (the first and second screenshot). If so, how would I do that.

The existing resources (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46094637/1330974) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---python-example)) that I could find online don't tell me yet. Any advice/tip would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using Azure Functions v1 or v2? The python languages work very differently, and are in different states. For v1, the language is experimental, and will always be. For v2, the language is in preview, but will eventually GA.

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon, I'm not sure how to check if I'm using v1 or v2. **If you do know how to, please let me know.** The only thing that I think might be relevant is that, under Function Apps Settings > Runtime Verision, it reads "1.0.12205.0 (~1)". 
Also, I figured out how to retrieve header information. It's to use: `os.environ['REQ_HEADERS_EXCELSOURCEPATH']`if the header's name is 'excelSourcePath'.

Comment: I highly recommend switching to a V2 function app (I believe that is the default nowadays). That version is far more supported for Python. Glad you figured out your question though. You should leave it as an official answer for others though.

Comment: @ConnorMcMahon Thank you. I tried to switch to V2 yesterday, but seems like I need to migrate my existing apps. But will definitely consider switching. :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out and am sharing what I found below so that it helps everyone out there wondering the same thing as i did.

This is the code I wrote in Python Function App to access the body and the request headers.

```
import os
import json

# This is how I'm currently reading the **body of the POST request**
postreqdata = json.loads(open(os.environ['req']).read())

# This is how we should read **a header of the POST request**;
# here 'excelSourcePath' is one of the header names.
postreqdata['header1'] = os.environ['REQ_HEADERS_EXCELSOURCEPATH']

# 'User Properties' is just for monitoring purpose
# https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8692cd00-307b-4204-a547-bed2030cb762/adfv2-user-property-setting?forum=AzureDataFactory

response = open(os.environ['res'], 'w')
response.write(json.dumps({'This is what I see from POST request now':postreqdata}))
response.close()
```

Hope this is helpful.